# Why am I unable to install MiKTeX after uninstalling it previously on Windows 10?

Tags: miktex, installing

After uninstalling MiKTex, I deleted the remaining folder in the program files directory and emptied the recycled bin. 
I tried to reinstall the program, but I got the following error: "The specified installation directory is not empty."
What can I do to successfully reinstall the program?
[image]

[image]

Comment: delete the directory manually (admin rights might be needed)

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE! As @naphaneal stated, deleting the directory from the command prompt or by right click on the icon can help you solve this problem.

Comment: What is a command prompt? From where do I delete this directory? I went to This PC>C>Program_Files and I do not see any MiKTeX folder.

Comment: Create a different directory, e.g. MikTex 2.9b, indicate it and continue.

Answer (score 2):

Copy that address and paste it in location bar .You will the see the MikTex folder .Delete it .And then try installing

Answer (score 1):

Copy the instalation location and paste it on File Explorer. Then, you will see a miketex folder. Just Delete that folder.
Example:

```
C:\Users\HTCM\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
```

Now, try install again. Done.